# Not able to fetch result from any twitter api with OAuth credentials obtained for version 1.1 using tweetsharp

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I am using tweetsharp with twitter version 1.1 to access data from twitter. I am able to login with OAuth from my application(Asp.net web application). I am storing the token and tokensecret in the cookies and when I am trying to access any twitter api, for example `/statuses/oembed.json?id=xxxxx` I am getting nothing. This is happening in my server. But when I am debugging the application, everything works as desired. I doubt that there is something wrong with the settings in the "My Applications" section in my twitter account. Or something wrong in the authentication method.

In the "My Applications" section in my twitter account I have given the following details:

- Website: http://test.mywebsite.com
- Callback URL:http://test.mywebsite.com/twitterauth/authorizecallback
- *where mywebsite is the name of my website.

The authorisation is working. But I am not able to fetch the data from the apis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. Let me post the answer which may help others in a situation similar to mine.

*The cause of the problem*: I was passing the values for twitter tweet ids from the view to the api with javascript. It is the problem of the javascript that it does not interpret the 'long' (64 bit integer) types as desired. It trims the digits at the end.

*The fix:* Enclose the tweet ids inside single quotes or double quotes to make it a string variable inside javascript. So no trimming at the end. Solves the problem.

Regards

Sunil